# How to set default (angle) to map, default value to rotateControl?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, rotation, maps

At a wordpress directory site, dubainurseries.com, I have the google map and my markers on it.
I want to load map 30-40 degree rotated into the page by default while it is on street view. Is there a way to do it? This is really necessary to use the screen more efficient to show more markers in a higher zoom.

Comment: `pitch` and `heading` for a `streetviewPanorama` may be set via `setPov()`

Comment: streetview is not available for that area... I want map to be rotated when it is loaded. Top of the map shall look to the north west instead of north...

Comment: ***streetview is not available** for that area* ...... *I want to load map 30-40 degree rotated into the page by default **while it is on street view*** ..you have to decide what you want.